# Image not inserting in folder using PHP and MYSQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

> Iam trying to insert image in folder using php and mysql but the image is not storing in folder as well as in database
>   This is my PHP Code

```
 if(isset($name)) {
$pass = base64_encode($pass);
$cpass = base64_encode($cpass);
$image_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$image_temp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$image_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
if ($image_type == 'image/png' || $image_type == 'image/jpg' || $image_type == 'image/iso' || $image_type = 'image/gif') {
    $upload = move_uploaded_file('uploads1/' . $_FILES['image']['name']);
      if($upload) {
          $reg_query = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO `quiz_register`(`name`, `email`, `mobile`, `password`, `cpassword`, `image`) VALUES ('$name','$mail','$cell','$pass','$cpass','$image_name')");
          if ($reg_query) {
              echo 'success';
          } else {
              echo 'fail';
          }
      }
  }
}
```

> This is my HTML code

```
      <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name" class="form-control" id="name"> <br>
      <input type="email" name="mail" placeholder="mailid@domain" class="form-control" id="mail"> <br>
      <input type="text" name="mobile" placeholder="Mobile" class="form-control" id="mobile"> <br>
      <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" class="form-control" id="password"> <br>
      <input type="password" name="cpassword" placeholder="confirm-password" class="form-control" id="cpassword"> <br>
      <input type="file" name="image" id="file" class="form-control" required> <br>
 </form>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have recently done this. here is what i used and it worked like a charm

```
$binary=base64_decode($file);
$file = fopen('../newSite/profileImages/'.$filename, 'wb');
// Create File
$is_written = fwrite($file, $binary);
fclose($file);

if($is_written > 0) {

    $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', 'pass','db name');

            $query = "UPDATE users SET image = '$filename' WHERE id = '$user_id';";

    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) ;

    if($result){
        echo "success";
    }else{
        echo "failed";
    }

    mysqli_close($connection);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
        $filename=$_FILES['image']['name'];
        $filetempname=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
        $fname=md5($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].rand()).$filename;
        $filepath="uploads/uploads1/".$fname;
        $upload=move_uploaded_file($filetempname,$filepath1);
if($upload) {
          $reg_query = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO `quiz_register`(`name`, `email`, `mobile`, `password`, `cpassword`, `image`) VALUES ('$name','$mail','$cell','$pass','$cpass','$filepath')");
          if ($reg_query) {
              echo 'success';
          } else {
              echo 'fail';
          }
      }
?>
```

---

You check this code it may be helpful to you .

Comment: This Code is helpful to you

Comment: i tried your code but when iam inserting, the image column is showing blank in quiz_register table and remaining values are inserting except image

Comment: where You enter image_name you use $filepath1 i am update my code

Answer (score 0):

```
just reviewed  your code i think the following code could work you please go through it and let me know if there is some issue..

<?php 
 $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");


if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
        $pass = base64_encode($_POST['password']);
        $cpass = base64_encode($_POST['cpassword']);
        $name=$_POST['name'];
        $mail=$_POST['mail'];
        $cell=$_POST['mobile'];
       $image_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
       $image_temp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
      $image_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
       if ($image_type == 'image/png' || $image_type == 'image/jpg' ||                          $image_type == 'image/iso' || $image_type = 'image/gif') 
    {
        $upload = move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],'uploads1/' . $_FILES['image']['name']);
        if($upload) 
        {
           $reg_query = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO `quiz_register`(`name`, `email`, `mobile`, `password`, `cpassword`, `image`) VALUES ('$name','$mail','$cell','$pass','$cpass','$image_name')");
           if ($reg_query) {
               echo 'success';
           } else {
               echo 'fail';
           }
        }
     }
}
?>
```